# How do I sum values in a column that match a given condition using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, data-analysis

Suppose I have a dataframe like so:

```
a   b
1   5
1   7
2   3
1   3
2   5
```

I want to sum up the values for `b` where `a = 1`, for example. This would give me `5 + 7 + 3 = 15`.

How do I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

The essential idea here is to select the data you want to sum, and then sum them. This selection of data can be done in several different ways, a few of which are shown below.

### Boolean indexing

Arguably the most common way to select the values is to use [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

With this method, you find out where column 'a' is equal to `1` and then sum the corresponding rows of column 'b'. You can use `loc` to handle the indexing of rows and columns:

```
>>> df.loc[df['a'] == 1, 'b'].sum()
15
```

The Boolean indexing can be extended to other columns. For example if `df` also contained a column 'c' and we wanted to sum the rows in 'b' where 'a' was 1 and 'c' was 2, we'd write:

```
df.loc[(df['a'] == 1) & (df['c'] == 2), 'b'].sum()
```

### Query

Another way to select the data is to use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to filter the rows you're interested in, select column 'b' and then sum:

```
>>> df.query("a == 1")['b'].sum()
15
```

Again, the method can be extended to make more complicated selections of the data:

```
df.query("a == 1 and c == 2")['b'].sum()
```

Note this is a little more concise than the Boolean indexing approach.

### Groupby

The alternative approach is to use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) to split the DataFrame into parts according to the value in column 'a'. You can then sum each part and pull out the value that the 1s added up to:

```
>>> df.groupby('a')['b'].sum()[1]
15
```

This approach is likely to be slower than using Boolean indexing, but it is useful if you want check the sums for other values in column `a`:

```
>>> df.groupby('a')['b'].sum()
a
1    15
2     8
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this without using groupby or loc. By simply including the condition in code. Let the name of dataframe be df. Then you can try :

```
df[df['a']==1]['b'].sum()
```

or you can also try :

```
sum(df[df['a']==1]['b'])
```

Another way could be to use the numpy library of python :

```
import numpy as np
print(np.where(df['a']==1, df['b'],0).sum())
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to assign the summations back into the frame as a column, then you can use `groupby.transform` to make the sums have the same index as the original frame.

```py
# group by values of df.a
df['b_sum_by_a'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('sum')

# group by whether df.a is 1 or not
df['b_sum_by_a'] = df.groupby(df['a']==1)['b'].transform('sum')
```

[image: res]