# Pandas dataframe - Sum a column wrt to values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, col

I have a data that looks like this :-

```
data = {"doc1" : {'a': 2 , 'b': 1,'c':3}, "doc2" :  {'a': 1 , 'b': 1,'c':3}, "doc3" : {'a': 1 , 'b': 1,'c':3}}
```

I convert it into a dataframe :-

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index')
```

Dataframe looks like this :-

`a  c  b
doc1  2  3  1
doc2  1  3  1
doc3  1  3  1`

Now I want to sum all the values in column b where column a values is 1.

So the value I want will be 2.

Is there an easy way to do this rather than iterating through both the columns ?
I checked other posts and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28236391/4589310) :-

This makes use of .loc function. 
`df.loc[df['a'] == 1, 'b'].sum()`

But for some reason, I can't seem to make it to work with my dataframe.

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: "But for some reason, I can't seem to make it to work with my dataframe." Could you give detailed description of "some reason"? The answer you find should work.

Comment: Hey,I made it to work with the below answer. But my code was also doing the same thing. Only I messing up the variables. Due to that, it was failing. Thanks a ton !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. See below.

```
>>> df[df['a'] == 1]['b'].sum()
2
```

Instead of using `.loc`, try just filtering the dataframe first (`df[df['a'] == 1]`), then selecting the column `'b'`, and then summing.

Edit: I'll leave this here for future reference, although depending on the version of pandas you're using, your solution *should* work (thanks, @maxymoo). I'm running `0.18.1` and both approaches worked.

Comment: actually this should be equivalent to the OP's code ... although maybe it's only in the latest version of pandas ?

Comment: Hmmm. You're right. I'm running `pandas 0.18.1`, and his solution still worked.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. I tried the code and it works fine but my dataframe is pretty huge with 10k columns and over 2k rows.  I need to calculate the sum many times. When I used the above code, it took a lot of time. Any faster way to do this ?

Comment: That's almost a different problem. How many different values are you trying to filter on? How many columns are you trying to sum? The above example should run very quickly with only 2k rows and one column filter. It sounds like a groupby method is what you're looking for.

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing that I mentioned above but on a larger scale. Going through 2k rows and iterating through all columns which are like 30k but only considering one column at a time wrt to another column.

Comment: What's the purpose of your analysis? From your `doc1`, `doc2`, etc. labels, it seems like you're doing some sort of text analysis using word frequencies. If so, might I suggest `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer`? Since that returns a numpy array, you'll be able to perform these sums *much* faster.