# Compute mean if two conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, mean

**Set-up**

I am scraping housing ads using Scrapy and subsequently analyse the data with pandas.

I use the pandas to compute the means and medians of several housing characteristics.

The dataframe `df` looks like,

```
district | rent | rooms | …
----------------------------
 North   | 200  |   3   | …
 South   | 300  |   1   | …
 South   | 300  |   1   | …
   ⋮         ⋮       ⋮     ⋮
```

---

**Problem**

I would like to compute the average rent for a *n*-room apartment per district.

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28236391/7326714) which brings me close, e.g.

```
df.loc[df['rooms'] == 1, 'rent'].mean()
```

but this computes the average rent for one-bedroom apartments for the whole city.

To do it per district, I'd like to do something like,

```
for d in district_set:
     df.loc[df['rooms'] == 1 and df['district'] == d, 'rent'].mean()
```

where `district_set` contains all possible districts.

Any suggestions?

I'd like to obtain the following table,

```
district | avg rent 1R | avg rent 2R | …
----------------------------------------
 North   |     200     |     400     | …
 South   |     300     |     500     | …
   ⋮            ⋮              ⋮
```

Comment: Use groupby and aggregate mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.groupby(['district', 'rooms'])['rent'].mean().unstack()` should work. `unstack()` turns the MultiIndex returned by the previous expression to a table with `district` as rows and `rooms` as the columns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Martin. However, this sorts the table in a different way than I want (see question).

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. Simply add `unstack()` to convert the MultiIndex to columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can collapse the dataframe by grouping by district and the number of rooms, then aggregating using the mean as @bigbounty recommended.

```
df.groupby(['rooms', 'district'])['rent'].mean()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer James. However, this sorts the table in a different way than I want (see question).