# Sum column based on another column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'MONTREGL':[10,10,2222,35,200,56,5555],'SINID':['aaa','aaa','aaa','bbb','bbb','ccc','ccc'],'EXTRA':[400,400,400,500,500,333,333]})
>>> df
   MONTREGL SINID EXTRA
0        10   aaa   400
1        10   aaa   400
2      2222   aaa   400
3        35   bbb   500
4       200   bbb   500
5        56   ccc   333
6      5555   ccc   333
```

I want to sum the column `MONTREGL` for each groupby `SINID`...

So I get 2242 for aaa and so on... ALSO I want to keep the value of column `EXTRA`.

This is the expected result:

```
   MONTREGL SINID EXTRA
0      2242   aaa   400
1       235   bbb   500
2      5611   ccc   333
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using `groupby`?

Comment: `print(df.groupby(by=["SINID"])["MONTREGL"].sum())` ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: can you do a `print(df.info())` and share the resulting print

Comment: The solution proposed before by @yatu worked but not in production `dfd= df.groupby('SINID').MONTREGL.sum().reset_index().assign(EXTRA=df.EXTRA.unique())` I get the error `Length of values does not match length of index`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ended up using this script:

```
dff = df.groupby(["SINID","EXTRA"]).MONTREGL.sum().reset_index()
```

And it works in this test and production.

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is old, but this might be helpful for others:

**Using loc:**
`df.loc[df['SINID'] == aaa].MONTREGL.sum()`

**Using groupby:**
`df.groupby('SINID')['MONTREGL'].sum()`

A similar question is answered in the following link (check Alex Riley's response):

[How do I sum values in a column that match a given condition using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236305/how-do-i-sum-values-in-a-column-that-match-a-given-condition-using-pandas)

Good luck,

Answer (score 4):

The code below works for your example:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["SINID"]).sum()
df1['EXTRA'] = df.groupby(["SINID"]).mean()['EXTRA']
```

Result :

```
       MONTREGL  EXTRA
SINID                 
aaa        2242  400.0
bbb         235  500.0
ccc        5611  333.0
```

Answer (score -1):

my suggestion would be to filter you dataframe with conditions related to other columns then apply sum function,

it goes something like this.

`import pandas as pd`

`df=pd.Dataframe({a:[1,2,3],b:[2001,2015,2019],c:[1,0,1]})`

`aux=df[df.c>0]`

`sa=aux.a.sum()`

`sb=aux.b.sum()`

My syntax may not be correct ( i didnt run the code ) but it will probably work and lead you to your answer

Good luck.