# Sum values for rows with multiple matching columns

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with multiple entries for the same year, metric, and country. I want to create a dataframe where rows with matching values for year, metric, and country are summed into a single row.

There are potentially hundreds of instances of matching values across the first three columns so the solution must scale well.

Initial data:

```
Year    Metric  Country         Q1      Q2      Q3      Q4
2016    2.1.1   Australia   23  166 146 17
2016    2.1.1   Australia   0   24  26  0
2014    3.1.1   Haiti           0   0   0   0
2015    2.1.1   Mexico          442 37  16  58
2013    3.1.4   Jamaica             
2015    2.1.1   Mexico          165 140 209 309
```

I have tried several iterations of groupby and boolean indexing from here:

[How do I sum values in a column that match a given condition using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236305/how-do-i-sum-values-in-a-column-that-match-a-given-condition-using-pandas)

Desired output:

```
Year    Metric  Country         Q1      Q2      Q3      Q4
2016    2.1.1   Australia   23  190 172 17
2014    3.1.1   Haiti           0   0   0   0
2015    2.1.1   Mexico          606 177 225 367
2013    3.1.4   Jamaica
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['Year', 'Metric','Country'],sort=False).sum()`

Comment: Where are your attempts ?