# Merge rows with same index on a single data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Products         Value
Product A        10
Product B        12
Product C        8
Product A        5
Product A        8
```

This is what im trying to do:

```
Products         Value
Product A        23
Product B        12
Product C        8
```

Is there an easy way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum). Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28236305/9758194)

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. Links provided by @JvdV should cover your requirements.

Comment: @moys - I not agree, else closed, because grouping by `index`, so cannot be used `df.sum(level=0)` in answer of dupe

Comment: df1 = df.groupby('Products').sum() this worked
thx

Comment: @jezrael `df.groupby('Products').sum()` meets the needs of the OP. `df.sum(level=0)` is a good alternative that can be added to the dupe so that all options are in one place. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @moys - yes, unfortunately only in pandas 0.23+ (because `Product` is index, not column)

Comment: @moys - cannot add to dupe, because in dupe is grouping by column, not by index.

Comment: @moys - Part dupe is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53404689/2901002), but without `set_index` cannot be used.

Comment: @jezrael No problem. I expressed what I felt. Sorry if it offended you.

Comment: @moys - I only explain why not close, but add answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) by `level`:

```
df1 = df.sum(level=0)
print (df1)
           Value
Products         
Product A     23
Product B     12
Product C      8
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) working in newer pandas solution too, if index has name `Products`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Products').sum()
print (df1)
           Value
Products        
Product A     23
Product B     12
Product C      8
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
df.groupby("Products")["Value"].sum()
```