# Creating new Dataframe by Indexing Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda, forecasting

I just can't seem to connect the dots on this. I'm trying to do something similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236305/how-do-i-sum-values-in-a-column-that-match-a-given-condition-using-pandas)

I have a dataframe that takes the form:

| Origination | Orig Balance |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | 3000 |
| Q1 | 2000 |
| Q1 | 4000 |
| Q2 | 3000 |
| Q2 | 3000 |
| Q3 | 1000 |
| Q3 | 4000 |
| Q3 | 3000 |

And I'm trying to create a dataframe that looks like this:

| Origination | Orig Balance |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | 9000 |
| Q2 | 6000 |
| Q3 | 8000 |

I don't want to set the specific parameters, so something like `df.loc[df['Origination'] == 'Q1', 'Orig Balance'].sum()` wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group by `Origination` first, *then* take the sum of `Orig Balance`:

```
sums = df.groupby('Origination')['Orig Balance'].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> sums
  Origination  Orig Balance
0          Q1          9000
1          Q2          6000
2          Q3          8000
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)?

```
df.groupby(by=["Origination"]).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use aggregate sum

```
df.groupby('Origination').agg('sum').reset_index()
```